# What to upgrade on a Raleigh MV7? 20"

Tags: road-bike, wheels, hub

I am undecided to upgrade the BB and crank or change a wheelset. Any advice on what might help me spend less effort pedaling?

I actually find a steel 26" MTB easier to pedal.

Comment: Why don't you get a steel 26" MTB?